# PHP: login to facebook and display photo album

Tags: authentication, facebook-login

I am working on a website that allow you to login to your FB account (fb login), and then displaying your photos, specifically that already been tagged.

I've tried the Facebook login API, and then displaying photo album on php (a Facebook page not a personal page). The thing is, i had problem when trying to code with the framework fuelPHP and when trying to display the photos of a personal page (not a Facebook page)

would you please show me the right direction? i mean it's my first time utilise Facebook API, the hard things come when i have to face the problem of retrieving the secret key, appID, etc.

Best Regards

Comment: Looks like your problem is not related to FuelPHP at all. Search for Facebook SDK beginner tutorials on Google. There are many. Also I'm sure Stack Overflow has this question a dosen times.

Comment: actually it is. i have utilised the Facebook API on a plain Html, but having problem when it comes to implement it on FuelPHP

Comment: Let's clarify this. Are you trying to use the Facebook API with JavaScript or with PHP? The Facebook API in general refers to the Graph API, so you still didn't mention whether you're trying to use the JavaScript SDK, or the PHP SDK. I don't want to just downvote your question, but without details it's useless. You should tell us: HOW are you trying to display the photo album? Also you say 'displaying photo album on php' which makes no sense in plain HTML. Viyancs tried to help you, but as you can see, it's a very general answer. Please provide more details.

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow is not really a place for these kind of questions. Similar questions get closed saying it's too localised. The questions should be already debugged, so they can be somewhat general, from which others may benefit as well. With very specific questions please try the FuelPHP IRC channel, or the FuelPHP Forums, or whatever fits the current situation. You can also get much faster response there, and you won't feel yourself attacked by comments like mine, and I won't feel I made you feel attacked. I hope you get I tried to help and not bash you :) (it's hard through comments)

Comment: thanks, no problem. you were just trying to help

Comment: Did you manage to get help? The forums, and the IRC are really good sources, you can get off topic help as well there.

Answer (score 0):

for developing facebook apps, maybe this can be help you :

1. create developer account of facebook , if you have already you can visit this link https://developers.facebook.com/
2. go to docs then find SDK what you want to choice, ex PHP SDK , there are tutorial how to use php sdk facebook for get data users in your case is how to get photo data who have been tagged by user. but the important thing is facebook has already more restrict on permission usage. by default we can fetch data user only 'email', 'user_friends','public_profile'. more than that you should submission custom permission to facebook, for step by step submission in here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review#submitlogin
3. after you're done with point 2 , time to integrated with fuelphp framework ,  fuelphp have auth package for managing login by social media here the link http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/auth/opauth/intro.html